# Help me to Combine two Tex into one Tex to Become Multiple Pages PDF that can be Converted to GIF with ImageMagick

Tags: animations

I have this piston animation from here:

[Improve code for four stroke engine in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448204/improve-code-for-four-stroke-engine-in-tikz)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\tikzset{
    relative to node/.style={
        shift={(#1.center)},
        x={(#1.east)},
        y={(#1.north)},
    },
    kolben/.pic={
        \node[fill=white,draw,minimum width=1.5cm,minimum height=1.3cm] (-a) at (0,0.2) {};
        \begin{scope}[relative to node=-a]
            \draw (-1,0.2) -- ++(2,0);
            \draw (-1,0.3) -- ++(2,0);
            \draw (-1,0.4) -- ++(2,0);
        \end{scope}
        \draw (0,0) circle(0.07);
    },
    valve/.pic={
        \draw[fill=white] (-0.175,0) -- (-0.125,0.05) -- (-0.05,0.05) -- (-0.05,0.15) -- (-0.075,0.15) -- (-0.075,0.2) -- (0.075,0.2) -- (0.075,0.15) -- (0.05,0.15) -- (0.05,0.05) -- (0.125,0.05) -- (0.175,0) -- cycle;
    },
    cylinder/.pic={
        \draw (-0.75,1.55) -- (-0.8,1.55) -- (-0.8,5.05) -- (-0.5,5.05) -- (-0.55,5) -- (-0.75,5) -- cycle;
        \draw (-0.25,5.05) -- (-0.2,5) -- (0.2,5) -- (0.25,5.05) -- cycle;
        \draw[xscale=-1] (-0.75,1.55) -- (-0.8,1.55) -- (-0.8,5.05) -- (-0.5,5.05) -- (-0.55,5) -- (-0.75,5) -- cycle;
    },
    crank/.pic={
        \draw[fill=white,rounded corners=1mm] (90:0.75) arc (90:270:0.75) -- (0,-0.1) [rounded corners=0mm] -- (1,-0.1) arc (-90:90:0.1) [rounded corners=1mm] -- (0,0.1) -- cycle (1,0) circle (0.05);
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \foreach \phase [
    evaluate=\phase as \x using {int(mod(\phase + 90,360))},
    evaluate=\phase as \case using {int(mod(\phase/180,4))},
    evaluate=\x as \d using {40*sin(\x)+50},
    ] in {0,5,...,719}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \useasboundingbox (-2,-2) rectangle (2,6);
            
            \coordinate (pivot) at (0,{3+sin(\x)});
            \coordinate (piston-top) at (0,{3+sin(\x)+1.3/2+0.2});
            
            \ifcase\case
            \colorlet{gascolor}{blue!10}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\valveone{1}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\valvetwo{0}
            \or
            \colorlet{gascolor}{blue!\d}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\valveone{0}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\valvetwo{0}
            \or
            \colorlet{gascolor}{red!\d}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\valveone{0}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\valvetwo{0}
            \or
            \colorlet{gascolor}{gray!10}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\valveone{0}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\valvetwo{1}
            \fi
            
            \draw[line width=14.9mm,gascolor] (piston-top) -- (0,5);
            
            \pic (cylinder) at (0,0) {cylinder};
            
            \pic (valve1) at (-0.375,{5-0.1*\valveone}) {valve};
            \pic (valve2) at (0.375,{5-0.1*\valvetwo}) {valve};
            
            
            \draw[double distance=2mm-\pgflinewidth,line cap=round] (\x:1) -- (pivot);  
            
            \pic[rotate=\x] (crank) at (0,0) {crank};
            \pic (kolben) at (pivot) {kolben};
            
            \node[anchor=base] at (1.25,3) {$ x $};
            \ifnum\x=0
            \fill[red] (1,3) circle (1.5pt);
            \else
            \ifnum\x=180
            \fill[red] (1,3) circle (1.5pt);
            \else
            \draw[->,red,ultra thick] (1,3) -- +(0,{sin(\x)});
            \fi
            \fi
            
            \node[anchor=base] at (1.75,3) {$ \dot{x} $};
            \ifnum\x=90
            \fill[blue] (1.5,3) circle (1.5pt);
            \else
            \ifnum\x=270
            \fill[blue] (1.5,3) circle (1.5pt);
            \else
            \draw[->,blue,ultra thick] (1.5,3) -- +(0,{cos(\x)});
            \fi
            \fi
            
            \ifnum\phase=360
            \begin{scope}
                \clip (-7.5mm,5cm-0.5\pgflinewidth) rectangle (7.5mm,3cm);
                \node[starburst,starburst point height=3mm,inner color=yellow,outer color=red,draw=orange] at (0,5) {};
            \end{scope}
            \fi
            
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{document}
```

another one is a water tank

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        
        \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
            \def\r{3}
            \def\H{1.5}
            \begin{scope}
                \draw[clip,-] ({\r*cos(-95)},{\r*sin(-95)})
                --++ (0,{-0.1*\r}) --++ ({2*\r *sin(5)},0) -- ({\r*cos(-85)},{\r*sin(-85)}) arc [start angle=-85,end
                angle=265,radius=\r];
                \shade[ball color=gray!15,opacity=0.5] (0,0) circle (\r);
                \shade[top color=blue!50!gray,bottom color=blue!20!white,opacity=0.6] 
                ({-\r},{-1.1*\r}) rectangle ++({2*\r},{0.1*\r+\H});
                \fill[blue!50] (0,{-\r+\H}) circle [x radius={sqrt(\r^2-(\r-\H)^2)},
                y radius={0.2*sqrt(\r^2-(\r-\H)^2)}];
            \end{scope}
            \draw[thick,->] (0,{-1.05*\r}) -- ++(0,{-0.3*\r}) node[right]{$v_e$};
            \fill[fill=black] (0,0) circle (1pt);
            \draw[dashed,|<->|] (0,0 ) -- node[above]{$R$} (210:\r);
            \draw[|<->|] (4,{-\r}) --
            node[fill=white,font=\footnotesize,inner ysep=2pt,inner xsep=0]{$h$}
            (4,{-\r+\H});
        \end{tikzpicture}
        
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: 1]
My question is:

1. How to combine them left side is the piston, right side is the water tank so when the piston finish 10 cycles the water at the tank will be empty.
2. You can use another code for the water tank, it is just an example from me.